# How to correctly refresh template of component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I’m using service with observer subscribing. Here is my InterfaceService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class InterfaceService {
  private contentFlag = new Subject();

  public getContent(): any {
    return this.contentFlag;
  }

  public change(): void {    
    this.contentFlag.next(true);  
  }
}
```

Here is my Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InterfaceService } from '../../-services/interface.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-content',
  template: `<div *ngIf="showContent"> My Content </div>`  // why it is always hidden ?
})

export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {
  private content$: any;
  public showContent = false;

  constructor(private interfaceService: InterfaceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.content$ = this.interfaceService.getContent();

    this.content$.subscribe(function(data) {
      this.showContent = data;      
      console.log('Here comes true:', data); // it works - here shows true
    });
  }
}
```

When other component makes interfaceService.change(), I get ‘true’ in console.

But there is no reaction in Component template. `<div *ngIf="showContent"> My Content </div>` is always hidden.

What am I doing wrong? Should I refresh template in subscription? How? Or is there a problem with architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are losing the scope of `this`. Use arrow functions to maintain the scope:

```
this.content$.subscribe((data) => { // here!
  this.showContent = data;      
  console.log('Here comes true:', data); // it works - here shows true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.content$ = this.interfaceService.getContent();

this.content$.subscribe(function(data) {
  this.showContent = data;      
  console.log('Here comes true:', data); // it works - here shows true
});
}
```